# Setting up MongoDB in Azure

Tags: azure, mongodb

If I want to run MongoDB in Azure, my options are:

- Using MongoDB Atlas.
- Setting up a Linux VPS and install MongoDB.

Is this correct?
My app is very small, few users and little data. Less than 3GB usage a month.

What would be the best option in my case?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Cosmos DB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction) is Microsoft's globally distributed, multi-model database service for mission-critical applications. Azure Cosmos DB provides turn-key global distribution, elastic scaling of throughput and storage worldwide, single-digit millisecond latencies at the 99th percentile, and guaranteed high availability, all backed by industry-leading SLAs. Azure Cosmos DB automatically indexes data without requiring you to deal with schema and index management. It is multi-model and supports document, key-value, graph, and columnar data models. By default, you can interact with Cosmos DB using SQL API. Additionally, the Cosmos DB service implements wire protocols for common NoSQL APIs including Cassandra, **MongoDB**, Gremlin, and Azure Table Storage. This allows you to use your familiar NoSQL client drivers and tools to interact with your Cosmos database.

Comment: Please don't post text wals.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend taking a look at Cosmos DB if you can. Because it supports the Mongo API you should be able to talk to it using the same code (for the most part) and it will then take care of the replication, backup, HA etc. for you.

Comment: Customer (and me) only want to use open source.

Comment: ok, well there is not open source Mongo as a service in Azure, so you would need to create a VM and run it there, but then you are responsible for updates, backups, HA etc.